# Convertir Objeto a documento multipartes (multipartFile) - Descargada y subida de archivos

Tags: javascript, java, spring

Hola tengo este require de parametros en el backend de mi aplicación

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/skills/excel")
    public ResponseEntity<?> loadExcelSkills(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
```

Cuando obtengo el archivo excel del frontend de la aplicación:

```
<input on-file-change="onFilesSelected" ng-model="excelFile" id="excelFile" type="file">
```

Realizo la captura del archivo en tipo js y necesito realizar el parseo a Multipartfile

this is my front:

```
$scope.saveSkillsExcelFile = function(archivo) {

    var file = new FormData();
    file.append('file', new Blob([JSON.stringify(archivo)],{type:'multipart/form-data'}));


    console.log(file);
    $http.post("http://localhost:9000/skills/excel?file="+file, {},{ headers: { 'Authorization': JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("authToken")) ,'content-type': "multipart/form-data"}})
    .success
```

Cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

Comment: First this isn't javascript is Java Spring and I think this fail is because you doesn't  config well your Rest controller for MultipartFile. Second if you think that fail is in Front side, put front code and not only backend code. In spanish: Pon el codigo del front y del back así no te reportarán.

Comment: sorry this is my back, and this is my first question in stackoverflow please be considered

Comment: The better way is you modify your answer and make more pretty or people go report you.

Comment: espero que se entienda mejor, Gracias Raúl por el consejo.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es subir el fichero?

Comment: Si, quiero importar los datos del fichero.

Comment: ¿Entonces el fichero ya lo subiste y puedes acceder a el?

Comment: Perdón, me explico mejor. El fichero lo tengo en mi pc y lo paso por el input de mi aplicación y quiero que el back me lo coja para que haga la inserción a la base de datos, lo unico que me falta es pasar bien los datos del front al back, ya que necesito ese parseo de objeto JS a MultipartFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### LA VISTA

La parte del html lo manejo con un simple form de esta manera:

```
<form th:action="@{/form}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
</form>
```

### CONTROLLER

Y en el controller lo recibes de esta manera:

```
@PostMapping("/form")
    public String guardar(Map<String, Object> model,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile foto, RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status) {

       // ... AQUI TUS OPERACIONES DE GRABADO, MODIFICADO, ETC.. 
        return "redirect:/listar";
    }
```

### SERVICE

La interfaz por aquello de los cambios que luego se requieran:

```
public interface IUploadFileService {

    public Resource load(String filename) throws MalformedURLException;

    public String copy(MultipartFile file) throws IOException;
    public boolean delete(String filename);

    public void deleteAll();
    public void init() throws IOException;

}
```

Este es el servicio que tengo preparado para la subida de ficheros.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.FileSystemUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Service
public class UploadFileServiceImpl implements IUploadFileService {

    private final static String UPLOADS_FOLDER = "upload";

    private final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public Resource load(String filename) throws MalformedURLException {
        Path pathFoto = getPath(filename);
        log.info("pathFoto: " + pathFoto);
        Resource recurso = null;

        recurso = new UrlResource(pathFoto.toUri());
        if (!recurso.exists() || !recurso.isReadable()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No se puede cargar la imagen: " + pathFoto.toString());
        }

        return recurso;
    }

    @Override
    public String copy(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        String uniqueFilename = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();

        Path rootPath = Paths.get(UPLOADS_FOLDER).resolve(uniqueFilename);

        log.info("rootPath:" + rootPath);

        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), rootPath);

        return uniqueFilename;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(String filename) {
        Path rootPath = getPath(filename);
        File archivo = rootPath.toFile();

        if (archivo.exists() && archivo.canRead()) {
            if (archivo.delete()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Path getPath(String filename) {

        return Paths.get(UPLOADS_FOLDER).resolve(filename).toAbsolutePath();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(Paths.get(UPLOADS_FOLDER).toFile());

    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws IOException {
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(UPLOADS_FOLDER));

    }

}
```

### CONFIGURACIÓN PARA DESARROLLO.

Esta configuración es para que mientras haces pruebas los ficheros se borren cada vez que reinicies el servidor. **CUIDADO PARA ENTORNOS DE PRODUCCIÓN**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDataJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    IUploadFileService uploadFileService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDataJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args)throws Exception{
        uploadFileService.deleteAll();
        uploadFileService.init();
    }
}
```

### ALGUNAS ACLARACIONES

En realidad es muy sencillo con el servicio. Solo ocupas llamar al servicio en tu controller con `@Autowired` para la inyección de dependencias (xP) y ejecutar tus validaciones.

Las operaciones son obvias:

- `load(String filename)` te permite obtener el archivo desde el servidor cuando ya esta cargado.
- `copy (MultipartFile file)` copia el `MultipartFile` que obtuviste desde el formulario hacia el servidor en la carpeta definida en `UPLOADS_FOLDER`.
- `delete(String filename)` elimina el fichero del servidor si es que existe.

En mi caso estoy trabajando con fotos, de ahí que muchos de los nombres se refieran a fotos pero sirve para cualquier fichero. La parte de la validación de tipo ya te toca a tí.

### RECOMENDACIONES FINALES

Te recomiendo hagas todas las pruebas primero en un formulario html. De esta manera no tendrás que estar pensando en JS y en el backend. El cambio despues es fácil.

> Confío en que estas usando spring-boot con anotaciones y no xml.

Comment: Muchas gracias Ángel, ya esta resuelto la clave ha sido el @PostMapping! Eres un crack!

Comment: @AntonioMaya Que bien! :D